# Anchor onclick bootstrap confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have jquery datatable which contain delete anchor each row. So if I click delete confirmation should display.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="" class="confirmation-callback">
  <button type="button" onclick="deleteInitialize(5)" class="btn btn-default" id="delete_row">Delete</button>
</a>
```

But I can't access this table row "a" tag through `$('#anchorid')`. So I used `onclick` event. But then the problem is I cannot get work this confirmation plugin to those anchors because of that same problem I explained earlier. Can someone please help me to include this plugin method inside onclick.

Here is plugin working [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/3/)

http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/3/

Comment: are you the one voting up my anwer? thanks! if this resolves your issue, you may also select it as the correct answer (big gray checkmark)... ;)

Answer (score 1):

[ **EDIT:** This will only work with a single row, have a look at my edit further down ]

Though it's a little hard to understand what you mean, but I think I know what you're looking for.

Simply include the confirmation function inside your `onclick` function as follows:

```
function deleteInitialize(data){
    $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation({
        onConfirm: function() { alert("I will now delete "+ data) },
        onCancel: function() { alert("Ok, I will NOT delete "+ data) }
    });    
}
```

I applied it to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/11/

**EDIT:** The issue was with the incorrect use of selectors (eg. you had `.confirmation-callback` on the anchor while it should have been on the button), plus you can actually get rid of the function used for `onclick` altogether and do it much more simple by using the `data` attribute, as follows:

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirmation-callback" id="delete_row" data-data="6">Delete</button></a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-default confirmation-callback" data-data="7">Click me</a>
```

and the JS:

```
$('.confirmation-callback').confirmation({
    onConfirm: function () {
        alert("OK, I will delete " + this.data)
    },
    onCancel: function () {
        alert("I will NOT delete " + this.data)
    }
});
```

And here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/13/

Comment: i think it's because you're using the same selector (`.confirmation-callback`) for 2 different lines.. let me see how that can be fixed...

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. But the problem is after I include this in to my code, first click nothing is happening. But if I click again then its works

Comment: just edited my answer, hope it's going to work for you now ;)

Comment: @webeno thanx for the answer.still no luck

Comment: @webeno As explained begining of my question along $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation not event works inside table. Thats why I used onclick event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62225/discussion-between-dushan-and-webeno).

Comment: sorry, i wasn't available... do you NEED the onclick? why so?